# Add div to javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add a div around some javascript code.

Here's the code I'm trying to modify:

```
slider.controlNavScaffold = $('<ol class="'+ namespace + 'control-nav ' + namespace + type + '"></ol>');

      if (slider.pagingCount > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < slider.pagingCount; i++) {
          slide = slider.slides.eq(i);
          item = (slider.vars.controlNav === "thumbnails") ? '<img src="' + slide.attr( 'data-thumb' ) + '"/>' : '<a>' + j + '</a>';
          if ( 'thumbnails' === slider.vars.controlNav && true === slider.vars.thumbCaptions ) {
            var captn = slide.attr( 'data-thumbcaption' );
            if ( '' != captn && undefined != captn ) item += '<span class="' + namespace + 'caption">' + captn + '</span>';
          }
          slider.controlNavScaffold.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
          j++;
        }
      }
```

Here's the resulted outcome when you add `<div class="container">` before the `<ol>` and closing `</div>` tag after `</ol>` in the code above...as you can see the list closes before list items make it inside:

```
<div class="container"><ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"></ol><li><a>1</a></li><li><a>2</a></li><li><a>3</a></li><li><a>4</a></li></div>
```

Here's what I'm trying to output.

```
<div class="container"><ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="">1</a></li><li><a class="flex-active">2</a></li><li><a>3</a></li><li><a>4</a></li></ol></div>
```

Code that isn't working:

```
slider.controlNavScaffold = $('<div class="container"><ol class="'+ namespace + 'control-nav ' + namespace + type + '"></ol></div>');

  if (slider.pagingCount > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < slider.pagingCount; i++) {
      slide = slider.slides.eq(i);
      item = (slider.vars.controlNav === "thumbnails") ? '<img src="' + slide.attr( 'data-thumb' ) + '"/>' : '<a>' + j + '</a>';
      if ( 'thumbnails' === slider.vars.controlNav && true === slider.vars.thumbCaptions ) {
        var captn = slide.attr( 'data-thumbcaption' );
        if ( '' != captn && undefined != captn ) item += '<span class="' + namespace + 'caption">' + captn + '</span>';
      }
      slider.controlNavScaffold.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
      j++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to show the actual code that's not working, instead of the code you started with.

Comment: which jQuery version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post it, but I suspect that you changed that first line to

```
slider.controlNavScaffold = $('<div><ol class="'+ namespace + 'control-nav ' + namespace + type + '"></ol></div>');
```

That will cause the code to do exactly what you describe, because the `.append()` calls will append to the outer element (the `<div>`).

Instead, leave that first line alone, and then at the *end* — after the `<li>` elements have been added — add this:

```
slider.controlNavScaffold.wrap( $('<div/>', { "class": "container" }) );
```

After that, in order to have things work properly when you actually add the stuff to the DOM, you'll want to find the parent of the `<ol>` and make sure that that's what you add:

```
slider.controlNavWrapper = slider.controlNavScaffold.parent();
```

(or however you want to keep track of it).

Comment: I added code I tried in original post above.  Pointy, where do I put that code?  I tried it in a couple spots and it's still not working.